# Custom field to wp_blogs

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite installation and I need and extra field to hold specific ID of every single blog. Wordpress does not allow me to change the ID that is to be created for the blog so I am looking for another solution - custom field. The point is I cannot seem to add one.

What I have tried is:

```
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id ); 
    $guid = some value I retrieve from somewhere else;
    update_option( 'guid', $guid);
    restore_current_blog();
```

that ain't doing anything to wp_blogs though.

Comment: IIRC `update_option` writes to `wp123_options` not `wp_blog`. Are you sure it's not getting saved there?

Comment: U r actually absolutely right! Just checked and wp_options holds the field BUT each separate blog doesn't. But anyway, I'm on the right track! Cheers!

Comment: "each separate blog doesn't" - oh OK: I meant that each blog should have its own separate options table with a different prefix and that the value should go in the right option table for that blog. If it's all ending up in the same wp_options table then I apologise!

Comment: No, for some reason switch_blog aint working in my code and the data is being recorded in the general wp_options, not wp123_options tables.